# Back-referencing in vim search

Tags: regex, search, vim, backreference

In my file I have text of type:

```
    1  module ABC(
    2  …
    3  …
    any number of lines
    n-1  …
    n   ABC …
```

I am trying to highlight both `ABC` in line `1` and `ABC` in line `n`.

I am using the following regex:

```
    /module \(\<.\{-}\>\)\|^\s*\1
```

However, this regex is not working.
It highlights:

1. `ABC` line `1` correctly and
2. Space between line beginning and first character on all lines which is not expected.

My end goal is to to change the `ABC` at both places to have the same prefix and suffix.

In this case lets say both `ABC`s get changed to `prefix_ABC_suffix`.

Please help me fix the search regex.

Comment: `May I know why is this not working please?` `\1` gets re-initialized for each line.

Comment: Its is searching correctly for the first part. For the part after \| it searches for beginning space and not for \1. I tired escaping backslash but then it starts searching for lines with beginning space and backslash.

Comment: I guess the bottom-line question here is how can we backreference a capture group that is in LHS of an `or` expression in the RHS.